# Laravel Resource route NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using the resource route to access several crud functions on my site but I am getting a NotFoundHttpException error when accessing one of several pages.  This was working this earlier and I don't think I have changed anything.

```
Route::resource('/contractors', 'ContractorController');
```

The specific ContractorController method:

```
public function skills($id)
{
    $contractor = Contractor::find($id);
    return View::make('contractors.skills')
        ->with('contractor', $contractor);
}
```

I have all of the basic crud methods located in the ContractorController too. I am using the skills method to create a new view that edits tags in a pivot table

my url is public/contractors/1/skills and this blade view:

```
contractors/skills.blade.php
```

Do you see anything that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only a few routes that Resource controllers by default will handle, you can see a full list of them (7 in all) in the documentation entry for [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

The `skills` URI segment is not one of them.  You will need to add a separate route for that:

```
Route::get('/contractors/{contractorId}/skills', 'ContractorController@skills');
```

However, this isn't really RESTful design.  You may be better off with a separate `skills` resource.

Comment: Thank you. I got it all working now.  Not sure why I thought I could run everything through one route!

Comment: Is it possible to generate two views off of one controller method? return View::make('contractors.edit') ->with('contractor', $contractor);View::make('contractors.photos')->with('contractor', $contractor);

Comment: You mean conditionally? Sure.. `if($condition) { return View::make(..) } else { return View::make(..);` In total? Not really. You can only return 1 response, and View::make returns that response. You can make your own response that contains the content of other responses, though.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it down now.